# Is there any way to look for Facebook/Twitter users by an image?

Tags: facebook, image, twitter, web-scraping

I'm trying to identify people profile through pictures.

I'm using tineye.com as tool to check if an image appears in any website, from the results, I scrap the url related with Facebook and Twitter and, if this exists, I go over the DOM checking if the image url is inside Profile Picture or in a comment.

That's very useful and very interesting to get a profile array but it is very limited because neither tineye nor Google Images Search have got a lot of Twitter accounts indexed. Moreover, Facebook profiles are not included in the results so I wonder if exists any place or any way to get Facebook/Twitter/Google profiles if I already have got a name and a picture.

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed by its TOS: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: I didn't know it. Thanks for the link